# Hi all, I'm getting an Error Campaigns Filed is Mandatory in new Leads from 2021. when i am trying to create a new lead

Tags: salesforce

```
QueryResult result1 = connection.query("select id, Name from Campaign where id='" + campaignId + 
"'");
LeadDetails lead = new LeadDetails();
lead.setFirstName(leadDeatils.getFirstName());
lead.setLastName(leadDeatils.getLastName());
lead.setSalutation("Mrs.");
lead.setIndus("sasadd");
Campaign campaign = (Campaign)result1.getRecords()[0];
lead.setCampaign(campaign);
SaveResult[] sr = connection.create(new SObject[] { lead });
```

I am new bee here. please help me out. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is it, integration that sends Leads to SF using SOAP API?

You will have to contact Administrators / Developers in charge of that Salesforce org. There's no standard lookup from Lead to Campaign so there's nothing to be made mandatory from 2021. [Here's list of standard fields.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm). And here's the entity relationship diagram showing that Leads (and Contacts) are linked to Campaign via many-to-many helper table called CampaignMember. ([bottom left](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm)).

Whatever error you're getting - it's probably new custom field/validation rule/some other thing the SF admins in your organisation did without notifying integration team.

P.S. If you have campaign id and there's custom `Campaign__c` field on lead or something -you don't have to query it? You probably could just call `lead.setCampaign(campaignId );` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Added Campaign Member to get fixed

```
CampaignMember campaignMember = new CampaignMember();
        campaignMember.setCampaignId(campaignId);
        campaignMember.setLeadId(leadId);
        SaveResult[] result = connection.create(new SObject[] { campaignMember });
        if (result.length == 1 && result[0].isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("LeadAssignment.setCampaignMember() : " + result);
            // lead.setAttachments(attachResult.getClass());;
        } else {
            System.out.println("LeadAssignment.setCampaignMember() : Campaign member added on lead " + leadId);
        }
```